# How can I find an exact substring using String.prototype.search?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```js
const ids = '[2][13]';
const myid = '1';

const result = ids.search('[' + myid + ']') != -1 ? 'found' : 'not found';
console.log(result);
```

this is returning `found` whereas it should be returning `not found` because id #1 is not present. However since `[13]` has a `1` in it then it misinterprets it. How can I fix this so it searches for the EXACT value match?

Comment: But "1" **is** present in the string.

Comment: Use a better regular expression. AKA escape the [ and ]

Comment: Understand that `[` and `]` are **metacharacters** in regular expression syntax. You have to quote them properly if you want to search for `[1]` literally.

Comment: search expects a regular expression. Maybe you are looking for indexOf

Comment: use an array. A string is a rather poor storage solution for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what your are trying to do can be achieved with `.indexOf` this returns index of exact match occurance or -1 in not found

you can check details about `indexOf` here [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```js
var ids = '[2][13]';
var myid = '1';

var r = ids.indexOf('['+myid+']') != -1 ? 'found' : 'not found';
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) you are using a `RegExp` which treats some characters as reserved for the pattern matching - angle brackets for your case.

```js
ids.search(/\[1\]/);
```

If you are assembling the expression manually, the backslash is **also** treated differently because it's parsed **twice**. The first parsing is for a conversion of string into a `RegExp` object (which uses `\` for special characters such as `\n`, `\t`, ...) and the second parsing is when the regular expression is utilized.

If you escape it only once (`\[`) it'll create a regular expression of `[` which is a reserved character, therefore you need to use `\\[` so that the first parsing converts it to `\[` and then a regular expression `\[` i.e. the **literal** value of `[` is used for pattern matching.

```js
var myid = 1;
'[2][13]'.search(new RegExp(`\\[${myid}\\]`));
// or as pointed out in the comments:
'[2][13]'.search(`\\[${myid}\\]`);
```

Comment: but what if its a variable? Does it work the same?

Comment: @CainNuke _"If a non-RegExp object regexp is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp with new RegExp(regexp)."_ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: `'[2][13]'.search(new RegExp(\`\\[/${myid}\\]\`))` and `'[2][13]'.search(\`\\[/${myid}\\]\`)` is the same.

Comment: @jabaa yup, makes sense

Comment: @CainNuke see the edits.

Comment: thank you although seems like indexof might be a little more practical.

Answer (score 2):

[`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) converts any string you give it to a *regular expression*. `[]` is special in regular expressions, it defines a character class.

I suspect you want [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), not `search`, which looks for exactly what you pass it.

```js
const result = ids.includes("[" + myid + "]") ? "found" : "not found";
```

(Or with a template literal:

```js
const result = ids.includes(`[${myid}]`) ? "found" : "not found";
```

)

Comment: sorry, this didnt work. It always returns found.

Comment: @Terry - Thanks! Editing error having copied the OP's code, forgot to remove the comparison! I've fixed it.

Comment: @CainNuke - See above, I had an editing error in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = '[2][13]';
let isMatch = function(n)
{
    return ids.match(/\[(\d+)\]/g).includes(`[${n}]`);
}

console.log(isMatch(1), isMatch(2), isMatch(3), isMatch(10), isMatch(13));
false true false false true
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The nasty trap is that you need to double-escape the square bracket

Whatever you pass into the `.search()` method is assumed to be a regular expression. In a regular expression, the "[" and "]" are the delimiters for a set of characters, allowing a match with any one of those characters.

For example the regular expression `[A-Z34]` will match with any capital letter or the digits 3 or 4.

Unfortunately your data contains `[` and `]` as characters within it.

You need one `\` for Javascript and one `\` for the regular expression parser, so that your code correctly looks for exactly the string `[1]`.

```js
const ids = '[2][13]';
const myid = '1';

const result = ids.search('['+myid+']') !== -1 ? 'found' : 'not found';
console.log(result) // found


const result2 = ids.search('\['+myid+'\]') !== -1 ? 'found' : 'not found';
console.log(result2) // found


const result3 = ids.search('\\['+myid+'\\]') !== -1 ? 'found' : 'not found';
console.log(result3) // not found
```